# Application served by uWSGI with Supervisord from Docker

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi, supervisord

I am trying to serve a Django application with uWSGI from Docker. I am using supervisord to start the process for me at the end of the Dockerfile. When I run the image, it says that the uWSGI process starts and succeeds, but I'm unable to view the application at the URL I thought would display it. Perhaps I do not have things set up/configured correctly?

I am not having supervisord start nginx right now because I am currently serving static files via Amazon S3, and want to first focus on getting the wsgi up and running.

I am successful in running the application using uwsgi locally by doing `uwsgi --init uwsgi.ini:local`, but I am having trouble moving it into docker.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Get most recent apt-get
RUN apt-get -y update

# Install python and other tools
RUN apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python-distribute
RUN apt-get install -y nginx supervisor
# Get Python3 version of pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-setuptools
RUN easy_install3 pip

RUN pip install uwsgi

RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties

# Install GEOS
RUN apt-get -y install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin

# Install node.js
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm

# Install postgresql dependencies 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql libpq-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

ADD . /home/docker/code

# Setup config files
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN ln -s /home/docker/code/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
RUN ln -s /home/docker/code/supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

RUN pip install -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/home/docker/code/supervisor-app.conf", "-n"]
```

And here is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = %dmy_app.sock
master = true
processes = 4

[dev]
ini = :base
# socket (uwsgi) is not the same as http, nor http-socket
socket = :8001


[local]
ini = :base
http = :8000
# set the virtual env to use
home=/Users/my_user/.virtualenvs/my_env


[base]
# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %dmy_app/
# load the module from wsgi.py, it is a python path from 
# the directory above.
module=my_app.wsgi:application
# allow anyone to connect to the socket. This is very permissive
chmod-socket=666
http = :8080
```

And here is my supervisor-app.conf file

```
[program:app-uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/docker/code/uwsgi.ini
```

From a MAC using boot2docker, I am trying to access the application at $(boot2docker ip):8080

Ultimately I want to upload this container to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, with not only a uWSGI process running, but a celery worker running as well.

When I run my container, I can see from the logs that both supervisor and uwsgi successfully start. I was able to get things running on my local machine both using uwsgi by itself and uwsgi through supervisor, but for some reason when I containerize the thing I can't find it anywhere.

Here is what is logged when I boot up the docker container

```
2014-12-25 15:08:03,950 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-12-25 15:08:03,953 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2014-12-25 15:08:04,957 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 9
2014-12-25 15:08:05,970 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you starting the docker container?

I don't see any CMD or ENTRYPOINT script, so I'm unclear as to how anything is getting started.

In general, I would advise avoiding things like supervisord unless absolutely necessary, just start uWSGI in the foreground from a CMD line. Try adding the following as the last line in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/uwsgi", "--ini", "/home/docker/code/uwsgi.ini"]
```

and then just run with `docker run -p 8000:8000 image_name`. You should get some reply from uWSGI. If that works, I recommend you move the other services (postgres, node, to separate containers). There are official images for Node, Python and Postgres which should save you some time.

Remember, Docker containers only run as long as their main process (which must be in the foreground).

Comment: Well I figured supervisord would be necessary for running a celery process in the container as well. I ultimately plan on uploading this container to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so I need all my processes running in one container, because EB gives no way to link containers (as far as I know). Also, I am not running a postgres server or Node application in this container, they are just dependencies of my django application.

Comment: OK. There are quite good docs on running supervisord here http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/. Remember you will need explicitly launch supervisor with your CMD or in docker run.

Comment: I have a CMD at the bottom of my Dockerfile, and I can see that the process is launched. I added the logs to the bottom of my original post. I still can't access the application in my web browser, however.

Comment: Are there any error messages on docker logs? What exactly is the problem? It now just sounds like a port forwarding issue.

Comment: Forgive me, I hadn't realised that I need to scroll the Dockerfile to see the CMD...

Comment: I would check if you can access port 8080 from inside the container e.g. docker exec CONTAINER curl http://localhost:8080

Comment: Nope. I'm getting `Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`. And nothing is being logged after what I posted above.

Comment: Ok. Now it doesn't sound like a Docker issue at all. I'd try just to launch and access uWSGI from inside the container and see how far you get. Post a new question if you have problems.

Comment: Got it to work. Although now uwsgi is weirdly saying it can't find my Python application...bleh. I've opened a new question for that one. Thanks for the help with this. It ended up being a port forwarding problem.